# Run time error with .txt files loading using getline, strcpy, strtok c++

Tags: c++, text, getline, strtok, strcpy

I'm having problem to load data from a .txt files. The problem is some times the code running perfectly but most of the time I just got an run time error. The funny thing is that I haven't made any changes to the code and there is some times the error and some times no error at all!

```
void CustomersDB::LoadCustomersDATA()
{
    string temp;
    char *str = new char[temp.length() + 1];
    char *p;
    int i, Temp;

    ifstream CustomerFile("CustomersData.txt");
    while (getline(CustomerFile, temp))
    {
        strcpy(str, temp.c_str());
        p = strtok(str, ",");
        string IDNumber = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        int Type = atoi(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        string FirstName = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        string LastName = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        string PhoneNumber = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        string DateOfBirth = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
        string Address = p;

        if (Type == 1)
        {
            CustomersDB::getInstance()->AddNewCustomer(new     RegularCustomers(IDNumber, Type, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, DateOfBirth, Address));
            i = FindCustomerIndex(IDNumber);
            p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            Temp = atoi(p);
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                CustomersDB::getInstance()->Client[i]->addAccountsToAllowed(Temp);
                p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
        }
        else if (Type == 2)
        {
            CustomersDB::getInstance()->AddNewCustomer(new GoldCustomers(IDNumber, Type, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, DateOfBirth, Address));
            i = FindCustomerIndex(IDNumber);
            p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            Temp = atoi(p);
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                CustomersDB::getInstance()->Client[i]->addAccountsToAllowed(Temp);
                p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
        }
        else if (Type == 3)
        {
            CustomersDB::getInstance()->AddNewCustomer(new PlatinumCustomers(IDNumber, Type, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, DateOfBirth, Address));
            i = FindCustomerIndex(IDNumber);
            p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            Temp = atoi(p);
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                CustomersDB::getInstance()->Client[i]->addAccountsToAllowed(Temp);
                p = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
        }
    }

    CustomerFile.close();
}
```

The .txt files contain the information separated by comas.

*303047898,1,Josh,Hardwell,050-8103580,7/7/89,NY,0*

Hope you will find the solution fast because I have tried everything and I'm lost!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `char` array of size `1` here:

```
string temp; // temp.length() == 0
char *str = new char[temp.length() + 1];
```

Then you use it as if it had a larger size here:

```
strcpy(str, temp.c_str()); // temp.length() > 1 after getline
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just adjusted the length of the string temp to 50(or anything big enough) and it's worked like a charm!!

Comment: @user3134453 Glad it helped. But your solution sounds fragile. As soon as you get a line that is too long your application will fall over.

Comment: It is a bit fragile, although that suits me perfect right now.